# PlotlyJS Mapbox density heatmap color inconsistencies

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

Upon reviewing the demonstration provided on https://plotly.com/javascript/mapbox-density-heatmaps, I have observed an issue with the coloring of the last heat map chart that displays earthquake magnitudes. When a user mouses out too much, the coloring appears to be incorrect. It is unclear whether this is intended behavior or a bug, but it does not appear logical to end users and seems like a bug.

For instance, if a user mouses out too far, numerous yellow areas are displayed, giving the impression that all of these areas have experienced 9-degree earthquakes. As a result, it appears as if nearly the entire earth has experienced a 9-degree earthquake, as shown in the image provided. However, when a user zooms in to examine specific locations, the yellow spots disappear, resulting in an absence of yellow spots. This behavior renders the chart significantly misleading to the end user.

I would like to inquire if you are aware of this issue. Is there a workaround or a setting that can be modified to prevent this from happening when a user mouses out too much?

[image: Zoom out example]

[image: Zoom in example]

[image: Zoom in example]

Same behavior has the previous chart as well, which is type of densitymapbox:

[image: Zoom out example]

[image: Zoom in example]

[image: Zoom in example]

---

However even if mouse in the colors are not right:

[image]

[image]

[image]

These 2 points above have very different values. One is 7 the other is 5.5. According to legend scale we should see different colors

[image]

But they are very similar and end user can not see the difference here.

You can test it here

https://codepen.io/pen?&prefill_data_id=7ef37bb4-967d-444d-b587-fee7363cc1c5
https://codepen.io/pen?&prefill_data_id=4648058a-b909-4075-869c-87c7d5fa2f74

or run this code:

```
d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/earthquakes-23k.csv',

  function(err, rows){function unpack(rows, key) {return rows.map(function(row){ return row[key];

})};


var data = [{

  lon: unpack(rows, 'Longitude'), lat: unpack(rows, 'Latitude'), radius:10,

  z: unpack(rows, 'Magnitude'), type: "densitymapbox", coloraxis: 'coloraxis',

  hoverinfo: 'skip'}];


var layout = {

    mapbox: {center: {lon: 60, lat: 30}, style: "outdoors", zoom: 2},

    coloraxis: {colorscale: "Viridis"}, title: {text: "Earthquake Magnitude"},

    width: 600, height: 400, margin: {t: 30, b: 0}};


var config = {mapboxAccessToken: "your access token"};


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, config);

})
```

OR this one:

```
var data = [

  {type: "densitymapbox", lon: [10, 20, 30], lat: [15, 25, 35], z: [1, 3, 2],

   radius: 50, colorbar: {y: 1, yanchor: 'top', len: 0.45}},

  {type: 'densitymapbox', lon: [-10, -20, -30], lat: [15, 25, 35],

   radius: [50, 100, 10],  colorbar: {y: 0, yanchor: 'bottom', len: 0.45}

  }];


var layout = {mapbox: {style: 'light', center: {lat: 20}}, width: 600, height: 400};


var config = {mapboxAccessToken: "your access token"};


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, config);
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. You also need to show some code in your post.

Comment: The code is in the link I posted at the start of the thread.

Comment: Your question is on the verge of closure by the community. I suggest that you take my advice and read the page. Your title still isn't a clear question and you need to show code _here_.

Comment: I did the changes requested

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the way a density heatmap works is that depending on how far you are zoomed in, points are aggregated together to produce a single value for a collection of points. Then a 2D kernel estimation is generated between all of those collection of points. However, when you aggregate points together, you can only choose one type of aggregation: it could be a count of the number of points, it could be their sum, the average, etc...

Looking at [the documentation](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/densitymapbox/#densitymapbox-z), the values are set by the z values which in this case are the magnitudes of the earthquakes. The more you zoom out, the more values there are for smallest pixel on the map, which is why you are seeing all yellow (the maximum value on the colorscale). When you zoom out and most of the map is yellow, this doesn't mean that the entire earth is experiencing earthquakes at a magnitude of 9 – it means that whichever parts of the map are colored yellow are experiencing a higher density of earthquakes relative to other parts of the map.

My interpretation of the density heatmap is that the color shows the relative density of earthquakes, and the numbers on the colorscale are there to show where the individual z values can fall between.

The color is determined by the kernel density smoothing function so when you zoom down to individual points, those won't necessarily be the same as their magnitudes. If you want the resolution to be at the level of individual points, you can use a scattermapbox instead – but you can't have both a density heatmap and a scatter.